# Can't Print PDF Document to a Printer in Document Viewer (Evince)

Tags: printing, deb, evince

Printing works in all other apps (browsers,scribes) but can't print to printer using Evince .

It's showing Printing complete dialogue(notification) but nothing happens.

I can print only in the flatpak version of evince but not if I installed through apt...

But In the evince flatpak the 'Only print:' option to print Odd/even pages is grayed out..

Thank you.

Comment: The issue automatically solved. at the same time the ui looks updated .. May be a update fixed my problem

Comment: again I can't print documents from Document Viewer. please help

Comment: Printing works in flatpak version (45) but not the deb version (42).

Comment: Please do not use comments to provide additional information. The comments are out channel to ask you for clarifications. Please add the Ubuntu version number you are using, the printer specifics including make, model, connection type (USB, WiFi, Ethernet cable), and if you installed any printer driver or if the printer works without driver.